# Vue.js - List rendering and method calls - Almost an infinite loop

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using `vue.js 2.3` and `element-ui`. I need to render a list of about 1000 item. For each item, I'd like to display a `tag` with a different color depending on the `availability` property of the item.

#### Problem

`Vue.js` is getting super slow when rendering the list and it is because of the function `getTagType`. Especially, this function is called each time the button `show-hide` is clicked.

#### Questions

Is there any other method to get a better responsiveness?

#### Ideas

I thought to build the `type-tag` in the backend but since it is just a display matter I don't know if it makes sense or not.

I thought about reducing the list using a `virtual-scroll` or `paging` but if possible I would want to avoid that

```
 <div v-for='cloth in computedCloths' class="cloth-card" :key="cloth.id">
    <div class="cloth-picture"></div>
    <div class="cloth-footer">
      <div>{{cloth.cloth_code}}</div>
      <div>
        <el-tooltip placement="top">
          <div slot="content" v-if="cloth.availability === 'qtyFull'">Full</div>
          <div slot="content" v-else-if="cloth.availability === 'qtyLow'">Low</div>
          <div slot="content" v-else-if="cloth.availability === 'qtyTempOutStock'">Out of stock</div>
          <el-tag :type="getTypeTag(cloth.availability)"><i class="el-icon-information align-center"></i></el-tag>
        </el-tooltip>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

getTagType(availability) {
      if(availability === 'qtyLow') {
       return 'warning';
      }
      if(availability === 'qtyFull') {
       return 'success';
      }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xvq8tn9d/

#### Answer from @Bert Evans

https://jsfiddle.net/xvq8tn9d/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incrementing your counter is causing the slowness. Incrementing the counter in your `getType` method causes a re-render, which causes `getType` to be called, which causes a re-render, etc. Remove this line and your code runs reasonable quickly.

```
this.counterFunction++;
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kzxepdp/2/).

I'm not sure exactly why you need it. It's going to be called for each row in your table.

Comment: I did it originally because it was slow so I wanted to debug. All those data are in a `el-dialog` component and I'm using `devserver` that might cause the slow feeling

Comment: This https://jsfiddle.net/xvq8tn9d/ is closer to the reality and it is slower. Especially when cliking on `show-hide` The function `getTypeTag` is called each time we click on the button even if I put `v-show` on the `div`

Comment: @Leo You're doing a lot of calculation on show/hide. I sped it up a bit by doing the calculation in your computed so it's cached. https://jsfiddle.net/xvq8tn9d/2/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.